# Getting the error citation undefined all the time

Tags: bibliographies

I am using LaTeX (for the first time, I am a noob) with `MiKTeX`, `Texmaker`, and `JabRef`. I want to use citations in my document and I have a `Refs.bib` file (inspired by this post: [Citation undefined error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/596908/citation-undefined-error)). In LaTeX I have the following code:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{Refs.bib}
@article{Markowitz1952,
    author = {Markowitz, Harry},
    doi = {10.2307/2975974},
    journal = {The Journal of Finance},
    language = {English},
    month = 3,
    number = 1,
    pages = {77-91},
    title = {{Portfolio Selection}},
    url = {https://www.jstor.org/stable/2975974},
    volume = 7,
    year = 1952
}

@article{Michaud1989,
    author =  {Michaud, Richard O.},
    title = {{The Markowitz Optimization Enigma: Is ?Optimized? Optimal?}},
    journal = {Financial Analysts Journal},
    volume = 45,
    number = 1,
    pages = {31-42},
    year  = 1989,
    publisher = {Routledge},
    doi = {10.2469/faj.v45.n1.31},
    URL =  {https://doi.org/10.2469/faj.v45.n1.31}
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

The classical \cite{Markowitz1952} asset allocation algorithm is the stronghold of
portfolio construction since its first appearance in 1952, however it is known to
output concentrated portfolios with unstable weights achieving poor out-of-sample
performances. \cite{Michaud1989} demonstrates its tendency to maximize the
errors within the input assumptions. 


\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{Refs}

\end{document}
```

However, when I try to quick build the document Texmaker gives me the error `citation undefined`.

[image]

I have been trying to solve this for hours without any success. Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Edit: Here is the log file of the run:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (MiKTeX 23.5) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.5.27)  28 MAY 2023 13:06
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**./Test.tex
(Test.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-05-15>

LaTeX Warning: Writing or overwriting file `./Refs.bib'.

\openout15 = `Refs.bib'.
```

Edit2: This error had to do with me using a build directory and is not related to [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-or-bold-citation-key-instead-of-citation-number).

Comment: You need to include a bibliography package such as `natbib` or `biblatex` etc, add `\usepackage{natbib}` to your preamble (before `\begin{document}` and see if it works, let us know :)

Comment: That did not work, sadly. I still get the same error. :( Edit: I only tried with `natbib` when I use `biblatex` I get an error.

Comment: Your examples works. You just have to run LaTeX (e.g. PDFLaTeX or XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX) + bibtex + LaTeX + LaTeX.

Comment: @cabohah I run PdfLaTeX + Bib(la)tex + PdfLaTeX (x2) + View PDF. Should I change?

Comment: Show the `blg` file of the BiBTeX run.  If it does not begin with `This is BibTeX` but `[0] Config.pm:307> INFO - This is Biber` you've run the wrong program.

Comment: @cabohah Where do I find the `.blg`file? Edit: I updated with the log file.

Comment: In the same folder, where you can find the `.log` file. If you are using Windows, please activate the showing of file name extensions of all files.

Comment: Yeah I have, but I cannot find such a file. Have I forgotten to install something?

Comment: If you do not have a `.blg`, you've not run BibTeX (or not given the basename as a parameter). Opening a `.blg` is the first thing, the program does, after reading the options an parameters.

Comment: How do I run that? I can find the .exe file but nothing happens when I open it.

Comment: With the default settings of TeXmaker, you can run it from the menu. If you've changed the configuration, reset it to the defaults. Alternatively use the command line, go to the directory with your document, run `bibtex <basename>` with `<basename>` replaced by the basename of your main tex file.

Comment: When I do it I get `I couldn't open file name Test.aux Process exited normally`

Comment: Aha! You are right. The problem was that I had a build directory in my settings enabled, but then LaTeX did not find the `.aux` file needed for the references. Restoring the settings solved the problem. A HUGE thanks for this help! I have spent 4-5 hours trying to solve this problem. You saved my weekend. :)

Comment: @JamesT natbib is not needed here, you just need to use bibtex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had a built directory in my settings enabled, but then LaTeX did not find the `.aux` file needed for the references. Restoring the settings solved the problem. @cabohah helped me with this solution.

Edit: Or one could use this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55037493/bibtex-not-finding-aux-file-within-texmakers-build-subdirectory

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!